# Evitando dois processos da mesma aplicação em Pascal

Tags: delphi, pascal, lazarus

Qual é a forma mais viável para identificar os processos da minha aplicação na memória e encerrá-las se há mais de uma execução. Utilizo a plataforma Lazarus IDE (parece com Delphi), na qual suporta a linguagem de programação Pascal orientada a objetos.

**OBS:** Mesmo que haja nomes de processos diferentes possa identificar minha aplicação.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O componente [**UniqueInstance**](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/UniqueInstance) pode fazer esse trabalho para você, para usa-lo basta soltar um componente no formulário principal, manipular a propriedade `Identifier`(utilizado para identificar sua aplicação) e ativa-lo.

Você também pode fazer isso utilizando a função [**`CreateMutex()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682411.aspx) para *identificar* a aplicação, se a função tiver êxito o valor de retorno será a *identidade* da aplicação, caso contrário, um valor nulo.

Caso já exista tal identificador antes de chamar a função, o retorno será o identificador para o objeto existente, nesse caso, ao chamar a função [**`GetLastError()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360.aspx), o valor de retorno será `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`. Isso na prática seria algo como isso:

```
var
  mutex: THandle;
  ID: string;
begin
  ID:= 'MyAppUniqueID';
  mutex := CreateMutex(nil, False, PChar(ID));

  if GetLastError = ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS then begin
    Application.Terminate;
  end;
end;
```

O trecho de código acima pode ser usado no evento `OnCreate()` do formulário principal. Para liberar o *identificador* você pode usar a função [**`CloseHandle()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724211.aspx) no evento `OnClose()` ou `OnDestroy()`, para isso a variável `mutex` teria que ser uma variável global.

Comment: Obrigado, me ajudou muito.

Answer (score 1):

Usa-se a função [`CreateSemaphore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682438(v=vs.85).aspx) do Windows. Se a função `GetLastError` disser que já existe um semáforo com esse nome, é que ja está rodando. Do contrario, não.

Trecho relevante da documentação da função:

> **Return value**
>
> If the function succeeds, the return value is a handle to the
>   semaphore object. If the named semaphore object existed before the
>   function call, the function returns a handle to the existing object
>   and GetLastError returns ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS. If the function fails,
>   the return value is NULL. To get extended error information, call
>   GetLastError.

Exemplo de uso:

```
repeat
sleep(10000);
createsemaphore("umnomequalquer");
until getlasterror <> ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS;
```

Comment: Preciso que funcione nas outras plataformas. Outra coisa é que gostaria de analisar a memória do processo e ver se é idêntica ou relativa, não somente pelo nome da aplicação.

Comment: Isso é em Pascal, poderia explicar melhor o uso?

Comment: Caion, fundi suas duas respostas numa só. Tenha em mente que você sempre pode editar suas perguntas aqui no site, e costuma ser preferível acrescentar mais detalhes numa resposta do que postar outra. Nosso site é um pouco diferente dos outros, dê uma olhada no [tour], na [help] e no [FAQ da Comunidade](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/699/faq-da-comunidade).

Comment: Poderia especificar uma outra forma, evitando assim o uso do "nome da aplicação". De preferência há um jeito para verificar a memória da minha aplicação e comparar com os outros processos? Assim se encontrar uma aplicação idêntica ou relativamente igual na memória poderia estar fechando.